# NSMutableArray init with getValue from Operation result

Tags: iphone, xcode, multithreading, nsmutablearray

i want to get back a return value (NSMutableArray) after an operation...

```
    [queue addOperation:operation];       
    [operation waitUntilFinished];
    [[operation result] getValue:&ParseAndCompare_result];   <<here is the error
```

> [__NSArrayM getValue:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x1b0010

how can i init this emtpy NSMutableArray with the new data i receive....?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ParseAndCompare_result = [operation result];
```